# Setup appium for Android on Mac osx 10.8.5

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, mobile, android, appium

**I am new to mobile testing. I want to configure appium for testing android applicaiton on Mac machine. Can someone provide the steps to do. And I want to using with selenium webdriver using Java.**

Comment: Is there something missing from the documentation that you need to know?  http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.2.0/?ruby#toc_0

Comment: I was searching for step by step procedure to configure Appium on a Mac machine. Is there any source available?

Answer (score 4):

While working on several projects I've described the following procedure to install Appium:

1. Download Android SDK
   `https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html`
2. Extract Android SDK to /usr/local/adt/
   `unzip -qo adt-bundle-*.zip -d /usr/local/adt`
3. Set ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME environment variables
   `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`
   `export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/adt/sdk`
4. Add ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME to sh profile (in order not to set them every time)
   `echo "export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.bash_profile`
   `echo "export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/adt/sdk" >> ~/.bash_profile`
5. Install Android build and platform tools
   `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/android update sdk --no-ui --obsolete --force`
6. Goto some directory and get Appium framework
   `git clone https://github.com/appium/appium.git`
7. Configure Appium for Android
   `cd appium`
   `./reset.sh --android --selendroid --verbose`
8. Start Appium server with
   `node .`

---

Feel free ask me if you any issues.

Comment: I have configured settings until step.5. Can you guide me on how to configure the settings for android in appium. http://www.dropmocks.com/mGf82g. I want to run the test on a real device(Nexus 4). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your Appium configuration looks fine at first sight. What problem do you face? P.S. Please remember, that Appium is just a server, you initiate test run from test code, and can change configuration/capabilities there as well.

Comment: So I followed the directions above and I can do stuff on a real android device, but I can't do it on emulator. I am getting this error: Unable to start Emulator: PANIC: HOME is defined but could not find .ini file in $HOME/.android/avd (Note: avd is searched in the order of $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd and $HOME/.android/avd)

Answer (score 0):

I can offer a new video tutorial:
[Testing Android apps with Appium - from setup to first test on OS X](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yatZBNufNVw)
That might be very helpful for this purpose

Comment: How about writing a descriptive answer here that might help the person asking the question. You may use links to articles and videos as reference may they may change or get removed over time.